# Entrada duplicada '2147483647' para la clave 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql

Me sale este error, al querer insertar en mi base de datos un valor con la misma longitud, en mi base de datos tengo 7 columnas las cuales son: telefono, nombre, apellido, direccion, email, password. El telefono es mi llave primaria.

Pero al querer introducir en telefono los 10 digitos(diferentes) me sale el error, ya que por ejemplo al insertar 4475936474 me lo inserta así : 2147483647, por lo que tengo que introducir un numero con menor longitud

consulta = INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ("Jhon","Reynolds","Hombre","19/09/1998",4475936474,"prueba@hotmail.com","1234")

Comment: Por favor edita y coloca la query que estás tratando

Comment: que tipo de dato es teléfono?

Comment: telefono es tipo entero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- El error sucede por que una columna de tipo `INT` tiene un tope o valor máximo de: **2147483647**
- Por lo tanto tu valor asignado de: `4475936474` > `2147483647`;  es decir el valor numérico que tratas de asignar supera el tope máximo de la cifra que puede almacenar.

**Propuesta de solución**

Usa `BIGINT` que tiene un tamaño máximo de:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Con lo cual podrás almacenar dichos valores, ya que se puede entender como multiplicar la base que es 2 63 veces

Puedes hacer un `ALTER TABLE` para modificar su propiedad así:

```
ALTER TABLE tablaNombre MODIFY COLUMN telefono BIGINT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Permitiendo que almacenes cifras con una longitud máxima de 19 números, claramente superior a las 10 cifras del tipo de dato `INT`.

- Ejemplo:

  4475936474111111111

O finalmente guarda dicho dato como *VARCHAR* especificando una longitud esperada.

**Referencias**

- [MySQL integer data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me funciono :)

Answer (score 5):

El número que estás insertando supera el rango del tipo `integer`, por eso te queda guardado como 2147483647, que es el valor máximo cuando se usan enteros con signo.

Tenés dos opciones:

1 - Cambiar el tipo a un `bigint` para tener un rango suficientemente amplio y no llegar al tope.

2 - Guardar los teléfonos como `varchar` con una longitud de caracteres suficiente. Esto es lo que yo haría, en general los tipos numéricos suelos usarlos en campos con los que voy a hacer algún cálculo matemático o para representar una secuencia de estados, o booleanos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda :)